# Generate a svc / wsdl URL in my WCF web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, svc

Usually when i implement a 3rd party WCF web service then i get a URL that ends with an `.svc` extension.

I just created a WCF Web Service in VS2010 and i'm able  to run that service, but i don't see any URL in the Test Client that ends with a `.svc` extension.

Is there something else i need  to do in order to get such a URL? Because usually from there people are able to get the WSDL also by adding `?wsdl` to the end like:
 `http://site.com/service1.svc?wsdl`

How can i generate such a URL in my Web Service?

---

This is what i have in my App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TestWebservice.Test">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestWebservice.ITest">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWebservice/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

---

## Edit

I removed the `mexHttpBinding` endpoint from my configuration file. When i launch my Web Service now it automatically shows a URL to a WSDL:

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWebservice/?wsdl
```

The `/` before the `?wsdl` part seems to be ***very*** important. Otherwise it won't work.

But that still leads me to my last question. How can i specify the URL to the `.svc` file? I'd like to have a URL like: `http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWebservice/Test.svc?wsdl`

---

## Edit 2

I got a bit further. I read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

So i created a `Test.svc` file in the root of my project with the following code:

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="TestWebservice.ITest" %>
```

Then i tried to access my `svc` file through the following URLs, but both didn't work for me:

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWebservice/Test.svc
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Test.svc
```

Is it even possible to host a `svc` inside Visual Studio? Or do i really need to host it in IIS first?

---

## Edit 3 - Fixed!

I finally have it working! I re-added the `mexHttpBinding` to my App.Config.

I installed IIS7. Published the Web Service to a folder in my `C:\` drive. Then mapped that folder in IIS and tried to request the `.svc` file in the browser.

At first it didn't work for me because it didn't recognize the `.svc` extension. Then all i had to do was enter the following cmd: `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` and now everything works fine.

Everything seems to be working fine now. Guess you can't request a `.svc` file when the service is hosted by Visual Studio. But it works when its hosted in IIS.

Comment: Please post your service's config file - chances are if you're using .NET 4.0 and didn't state an address for your service, it's using fileless activation (assuming its hosted in IIS).

Comment: @Tim Added my App.Config

Comment: No .svc file specified.  Have you tried simply appending `?wsdl` to the address in the WCF Test Client?

Comment: @Tim Just tried it. The Test Client gives me this URL (i added the `wsdl` to it): `http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWebservice/mex?wsdl`. But that gives me a blank page. I also have no idea how to specify a `.svc` file. This is my first WCF service. Could you perhaps point me in the right direction? I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWebservice?wsdl` - note that I removed `/mex` from the URL.  Is this hosted in IIS or self-hosted?  You mentioned App.config, so I'm thinking the latter.

Comment: @Tim Same thing, blank page. It's self-hosted from within VS2010. - Just noticed that IE says ***Page not found (error 400)***. FireFox simply displays a blank page.

Comment: Hmm....not sure.  I have to go for now (sorry), but I'll try to look at it tomorrow if someone else doesn't answer first.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  You should post your solution as an answer for future users (you can also accept it as the answer).

Comment: Could you please post your solution?

Comment: It is not required, its optinal.